# Latest MVC forms authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-membership, simplemembership

I'm trying to implement asp.net membership (forms version) using VS2012 and MVC4.
I've created the database tables using aspnet_regsql.exe and now I want to configure the web.config so I can run the 'asp.net configuration' utility in visual studio.
It seems I might be needing to use 'simplemembership'. Is this correct, and where can I get instructions on how to configure whichever one I need?
Thank you

Comment: You can use anyone of them, I am using sqlmembership provider in vs2012 mvc4 app, coz I have my customised functions which I have been using in mvc2 and mvc3 apps for membership and role management. can u post your web.config file so that I can help u?

Answer (score 0):

By default ASP.NET MVC 4 uses the SimpleMembership provider which is a lightweight version of the full provider. It doesn't expose all the functionality of the full version.

The membership provider that you want to use is configured inside the `<membership>` section of your web.config.

So for example if you wanted to configure the full membership provider (as used in MVC 3):

```
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
    <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" 
             type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" 
             connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" 
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
             enablePasswordReset="true" 
             requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
             requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
             minRequiredPasswordLength="6" 
             minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
             passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
             applicationName="/" 
         />
    </providers>
</membership>
```

Comment: I already have that much, which I copied from an older project. I also have the equivalent <roleManager> and a connection string set in <connectionStrings> applied to both. The error is "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies". Before I try to fix this, would I be better using the SimpleMembership provider?

Comment: Whether you should use the SimpleMembershipProvider is an answer I cannot give you. You should decide based on your requirements. As I said the SimpleMembership provider is a stripped down version of the full provider. So if you don't need all the functionality of the full provider you could use it of course.